# CakePHP how to create functions and call them from view

Tags: php, function, cakephp

How can I create functions that can be called in view (like in the index.ctp)?

I just wrote a function in one of my controllers:

```
public function getName($id) {
    $name = $users
      ->find()
      ->where(['id' => $id ])
      ->first()
      ->username;
    return $name;
}
```

The function should return the username according to the $id passed as a parameter. I just want to know how can I call a function from within my views. I'm getting this error:

> "Error: Call to undefined function getName()"

Comment: That shouldn't be *done* in the view. That should be done in the controller and *passed* to the view.

Comment: I wrote the function in my controller. The same controller that has those functions like index, add, edit, delete, etc

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you want to call this function `getWins()` from within the view `index.ctp` right? Please mention the CakePHP version you're using. Also, show the code written in this function.

Comment: Yes, that is it! I'm using CakePHP 3.0. Here is one of my functions:

public function getName($id) {

        $name = $users->find()->where(['id' => $id ])->first()->username;

        return $name;
    }

I can't call it from index.ctp

Comment: @Rockman So, in your controller function that's rendering the view, do `$this->set('name', $this->getName(123));` and the variable `$name` will be in your view. http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html#setting-view-variables

Comment: @ceejayoz Thanks for trying to help, but that didn't work. I just wanted to call a function from within the view, the function should display the username according to the id passed as a parameter.

Comment: @Rockman You should read up on MVC and why views aren't supposed to do stuff like that. We can't help you if you just say "that didn't work" without details, because doing this sort of thing properly is *definitely* possible.

Answer (score 1):

For doing such type of work you may use cakePHP Cell

```
//src/View/Cell/UserCell.php
namespace App\View\Cell;
use Cake\View\Cell;

class UserCell extends Cell{

    public function getName($id) {
        $users = TableRegistry::get('Users');// or may use $this->loadModel('Users');
        $name = $users->find()->where(['id' => $id ])->first()->username;
    return $name; 
    }
}
```

Now you can call from view

```
echo $this->cell('User::getName', [$id]);
```

Here is the [Official Doc](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/cells.html)

Comment: Where would `$users` come from in your method ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, but it is against MVC-model and is not in anyway recommended.

```
Namespace\ControllerName::getName(1)
```

You should really consider taking look CakePHP manual and understand, how to set variables to view from controller http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views.html#setting-view-variables

Other option would be making AJAX-request to your controller, if you want get data based on for e.g. user actions in view.